# Searching for ;;; finds all questions in Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, search

Searching for `;;;` enumerates the entire questions database in Stack Overflow. I assume that this happens in other stack exchange sites. Other searches like ... or `%%%` do not have such a problem.

This query is also presumably expensive since it takes 5.09 s to respond.

Matt shows in the comments that searching for `******` is even *more* problematic. (Please do *not* test this on SO itself, it takes a long time to complete and likely loads the server a lot, you can test on a smaller site).

[image]

A possible fix would be to check the length of the query *after* stripping characters such as `;` and verifying that it is non zero.

P.S

That's what I get for talking about LISP :(

Comment: Try quoting the search term like this `";;;"`

Comment: @user000001 [yup](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3B%3B%3B%22)

Comment: I guess there is no problem if we all at the same time just try now this expensive request ? :)

Comment: You can try the same search on meta - only 142k results, so probably safer. :)

Comment: The request is fun, by default it shows the most upvoted answers first. I now know which answers are the most upvoted ever on SO.

Comment: @user000001 Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine This is absolutely your fault for making me learn common lisp by the way :)

Comment: @jcsanyi To be sure that Benjamin wasn't lying I tested it on the main site, with a different number of semicolons to ensure it wasn't cached. Not that I recommend it of course (yeah, I tested it, no need for you to do it).

Comment: A lot of punctuation-only queries return the full list.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Nothing that you can't get by going to the questions tab.

Comment: ... in fact, some seem even more intensive than just `;;;`. `******` takes ~30 seconds, for example.

Comment: @Matt WOW, that takes _so_ long :/ I wonder why it takes so much time

Comment: Why arent there time limits on queries?

Comment: @dystroy: the Earth will explode, like the Alf's homeplanet.

Comment: I've played with search on Meta, and not only `******` return 143k results, but also single `*` does. I'm not really skilled in the stack search engine. Is it a wildcard? It seems partial.. `rub*` found `ruby`, but `ru*y` did not.

Comment: ITT: Stack Exchange search sucks.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - Searching `is:answer` and sorting by votes would be better.

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah, I never bothered tbh.

Comment: Searching for `***` also returns all questions... but I suppose that is `by-design`? [SO: "16,144,915 results"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=***)

Comment: Hmmm... imagine if that happened with Google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer the case.  We take a look at these symbol searches and try to help you out here.

For example, [try searching for `;;;` on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=;;;) and you'll see it gets redirected to `";;;"` (we don't actually redirect the URL).  We perform the raw search...notice elastic (Lucene really) stripped all the characters and effectively did a `match_all`, then we quote the phrase to get much more appropriate results, if there are any for the quoted version.

It's basically the addition of the second search that changed here, it shouldn't break any previous cases because if they return results then this new path never gets invoked.

Comment: Sorry @NickCraver, unaccepting. I just noticed this still happens when searching for stars http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*** (Should I open a new bug?)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I should probably special case that *exact* search, * is a wildcard operator so it makes no sense by itself.  I'll take a look in the morning when time allows.

Comment: can you remove the [tag:status-completed] tag?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum why? What's not behaving as intended? * is a wildcard, the behavior there is correct.

Comment: So stackoverflow.com/search?q=***  is correct behavior? Should I open a new question?